# Find the radius of the circle??

Tags: geometry

[image]

$|AP|=12cm,$ $|BP|=4cm,$ $|OP|=11cm.$ Find the radius. Help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brk2W.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $$|AP|\cdot |PB|=|DP|\cdot |PC|$$
but letting the radius be $r$, 
$$|DP|=r+|OP|=r+11$$ and $$|PC|=|OC|-|OP|=r-11$$
thus
$$12\times4=(r+11)(r-11)=r^2-121$$
or $$r^2=169$$ and $$r=13$$